# How to understand the loss function in scikit-learn logestic regression code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, loss-function

The code for the loss function in scikit-learn logestic regression is:

```
# Logistic loss is the negative of the log of the logistic function.
    out = -np.sum(sample_weight * log_logistic(yz)) + .5 * alpha * np.dot(w, w)
```

However, it seems to be different from common form of the logarithmic loss function, which reads:

```
-y(log(p)+(1-y)log(1-p))
```

(please see http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Log_Loss)

Could anyone tell me how to understand to code for  loss function in scikit-learn logestic regression and what is the relation between it and the general form of the logarithmic loss function?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should note that `0.5 * alpha * np.dot(w, w)` is just a normalization. So, sklearn logistic regression reduces to the following

`-np.sum(sample_weight * log_logistic(yz))`

Also, the `np.sum` is due to the fact it consider multiple samples, so it again reduces to

`sample_weight * log_logistic(yz)`

Finally if you read [HERE](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L998), you note that sample_weight is an optional array of weights that are assigned to individual samples. If not provided, then each sample is given unit weight. So, it should be equal to one (as in the original definition of cross entropy loss we do not consider unequal weight for different samples), hence the loss reduces to:

`- log_logistic(yz)`

which is equivalent to

`- log_logistic(y * np.dot(X, w))`.

Now, why it looks different (in essence it is the same) from the cross entropy loss function, i. e.:

`- [y log(p) + (1-y) log(1-p))]`.

The reason is, we can use either of two different labeling conventions for binary classification, either using `{0, 1}` or `{-1, 1}`, which results in the two different representations. But they are the same!

More details (on why they are the same) can be found [**HERE**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250937/which-loss-function-is-correct-for-logistic-regression). Note that you should read the response by **Manuel Morales**.

Comment: Hello Meysam Sadeghi,                                                                                            You answer is very helpful. Thanks a lot. And I have another question: what is the relationship between "sample_weight" and "class_weight" in the scikit-learn logestic regression?                                                              Best wishs!

Comment: I try my best to explain briefly:


class_weights can be used to handle the cases where you have unequal amount of data in different classes. Assume 1000 patients that you test for a rare cancer and 990 are healthy and 10 has cancer. Then if your model always tell you everyone is healthy, it has accuracy 0.99%. But if (for example) you weight the classes inversely  proportional to the number of samples (1000/10 = 100 for cancer cases and 1000/990=1.01) you can handle this.

Comment: ... Continue...
sample_weights are used to give importance on the samples that you are more interested/concerned about. Assume you have 100 sample, but 10 of them (the class they belong is not important, but the samples themselves are important, so let us assume 5 positive and 5 negative samples in a binary classification problem) are coming from a competition that you are going to compete and the rest (the other 90) are just some data that you found from web and are not as important.

Comment: ....Continue...

Then, you can set a higher sample_weight for those 10 samples and be sure they are properly emphasized when you train a model.